# UICollectionViewCell place cells side by side in landscape mode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two stacked UICollectionViewCell's in my app in both portrait and landscape modes. However when in landscape mode I would like the cells to switch to side by side and rotate any of their contents appropriately as well. How do I do this? I am using xcode 8 and swift.

Comment: No. Basically what I want is that the cells stack in portrait mode (one on top of the other). But they are side by side when in landscape mode. Kind of like what happens with bootstrap columns.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you will need to detect orientation changes on the screen and when you detect landscape or portrait, change the Scroll Direction property to the one that you want either vertical or horizontal.

Comment: Yep that worked for me. How can I give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you will need to detect orientation changes on the screen and when you detect landscape or portrait, change the Scroll Direction property to the one that you want either vertical or horizontal.